# Is there a more succinct way to type hint `Union[NDArray[np.float64], Sequence[float]`?

Tags: python, numpy, typing

Suppose there is a function that takes numpy arrays as inputs, but it's okay if a user passes in lists (which is often the case). What's a right way to hint that:

1. The function does numpy-based arithmetic.
2. But it's okay to provide lists (or sequences).
3. The underlying data type is `T`. So it could be that `T` is `np.float64`.

Is `Union[NDArray[np.float64], Sequence[float]]` the most succinct way short of making a type alias to that?

Comment: What does your function do that it accepts either? If it just turns a `Sequence[float]` into an array before using the array, I would just make the *caller* responsible for the conversion, so that your function need *only* accept arrays.

Comment: A trivial change would be to use `NDArray[np.float64] | Sequence[float]` instead of using `Union` directly.

Comment: @chepner I refer to the fact that many numpy functions accept lists instead of arrays: eg `np.linalg.norm([1, 1])`. Some other libraries also accept lists instead of numpy arrays and it may or may not be that they are doing conversion under the hood. Requiring the caller to do a conversion when not necessary may entail an unnecessary copy (because turning a list into a numpy array means the underlying data is copied).

Comment: @chepner for your second comment, yes I suppose that is more succinct. I was hoping for something like `numpy.typing.ArrayLike[float]` though. But it seems `ArrayLike` is not a `GenericAlias`.